# Estimating mix-level logistic regression coefficients without using lme4 package in R

Tags: r, subset, logistic-regression, lme4, mixed-models

I have a 2 level dataset of 37000 instances, which represents the choices of 199 subjects. I have to estimate coefficients in logistic regression for each of the 199 individuals. I have done manually 199 times by subsetting, but I want to know whether there is a more efficient way of getting the coefficients by looping without using the lme4 package. Also, I should compute the coefficients as variables in each subject.

Here is my code.

```
### Split of the dataset in each subject ID
mylist <- split(df_merged2, df_merged2$sjind)

### Indication of subject 1 in the first subsetting
df1 <- mylist[[1]]

### Logistic regression

glm1 <- glm(rep ~ reward_v.2 + trans_v.2 + reward_transition, data = df1)   

### Extracting the coefficients
reward_transition <- coef(glm1)[4] 

reward <- coef(glm1)[2] 

transition <- coef(glm1)[3] 

reward<- as.numeric(reward)

reward_transition <- as.numeric(reward_transition)

transition <- as.numeric(transition)

omega <- reward_transition - reward

### Computing the constant coefficients as variables

df1$rewardmix <- 1

df1$rewardmix <- reward

df1$omega <- 1

df1$omega <- omega
df1$transmix <- 1

df1$transmix <- transition

df1$reward_transitionmix <- reward_transition
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you make the example reproducible by proving sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `by()` function from the base package, whose short description is **"Apply a Function to a Data Frame Split by Factors"** (ref: `help(by)`)

Here is an example using your terminology for the data frame and the subject ID variable names:

```
# Make the simulated data reproducible
set.seed(1717)

# The IDs can be sorted in any order
ids = c('A','B','B','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C','B','C')

# Sample data frame with: subject ID, target variable (y), input variable (x)
df_merged2 = data.frame(sjind=ids,
                        y=rnorm(length(ids)),
                        x=rnorm(length(ids)))
head(df_merged2)
```

The top 6 rows of the data look like:

```
  sjind          y          x
1     A -1.4548934  1.1004932
2     B -1.7084245 -0.7731208
3     B  2.1004557 -1.6229203
4     A -1.0283021  0.4233806
5     A  0.4133888  1.2398577
6     B -1.4104637  0.3746706
```

Now use the `by()` function to fit a GLM model for each group defined by the `sjind` unique values:

```
glm_by_sjind = by(df_merged2, as.factor(df_merged2$sjind),
                              function(df) glm(y ~ x, data=df))
```

The output object `glm_by_sjind` is a list with the following properties:

- It has as many elements as the number of unique values in `sjind` (in this case 3)
- It is indexed by the unique values of the `sjind` variable (in this case `"A"`, `"B"`, `"C"`)
- Each element contains the regression output from `glm()` run on each split of the input data frame (where splits are clearly defined by the `sjind` unique values)

So for example, you can request the summary of the regression output for subject `"B"` as follows:

```
> summary(glm_by_sjind[["B"]])

Call:
glm(formula = y ~ x, data = df)

Deviance Residuals: 
       2         3         6         7         8        12  
-1.40226   1.59040  -0.00186   0.06400  -1.93118   1.68091  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  -1.0487     0.7472  -1.404    0.233
x            -0.9605     0.9170  -1.047    0.354

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 2.763681)

    Null deviance: 14.087  on 5  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 11.055  on 4  degrees of freedom
AIC: 26.694

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2
```

---

If we go a little further, we can also perform a **sanity check** that each GLM model is based on the expected number of cases (i.e. the number of cases in each model should be equal to the frequency distribution of the `sjind` variable in the input data frame).

```
freq_sjind_in_data = as.list( table(df_merged2$sjind) )
ncases_in_each_glm = lapply( glm_results, function(glm) NROW(glm$data) ) 
all.equal( freq_sjind_in_data,
           ncases_in_each_glm )
```

which returns `TRUE`.

Or also inspect that visually:

```
as.data.frame(freq_sjind_in_data)
as.data.frame(ncases_in_each_glm)
```

which return

```
  A B C
1 3 6 4
```

in both cases.

Comment: Thank you, I will try your solution.

Comment: OK, let me know how it went and, if it worked for you, please consider accepting my answer so that other people can see that and I get credited. Here is more information about the procedure to follow when someone answers your question: stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers . Thanks!

Comment: Hi @mastropi, I run the code, and it worked. There is a formal way to accept your answer? I want to help you, but I am new posting in StackOverflow, so I don't know how does it work.